# I don't receive verification code for mobile in flutter application using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I use mobile verification in my app with firebase. So I tried it in debug mode and using emulator it works with no problems, I receive the code and I use it, it works
But when I deployed my app to the play store using the same code, and I follow the same process, I can't receive the verification code. In debug mode I mean when I plug the phone to the computer and install the app on it, now in debug mode and emulator it works but in play store it doesn't. Please if anyone has explanation for that let me know
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same phone number again and again it could be ban.. you have to set it under `Firebase -> Authentication -> sign-in methods -> phone -> phone numbers for tests`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually no, I am using different phone numbers and none of them is working when I deployed the app to the play store and all of them worked with the debug mode